# Inrush current from DC motors causing Arduino to reset

Tags: arduino, current, inrush-current

I've got an Arduino controlling a relay.  The relay controls two small DC motors.  All of these components are powered through a 9v power regulator.  I need the power regulator because the power source is a 16 volt battery, which would fry the motors and arduino if I connected them directly.

When the Arduino powers on the relay is initially open so the motors are powered off.  The problem comes when the Arduino switches on the relay and motors start.  The inrush current overloads the regulator and as a result, the Arduino loses voltage and resets.  I have determined from experimentation that the regulator has enough ampacity to handle the DC motors at steady state, it's just the inrush that is the problem.

I am very inexperienced in this area, so it's not clear to me how to solve this problem.  Might I use a capacitor to provide power to the arduino during the inrush period?  Or maybe a capacitor could be charged up and provide power to motors on startup?  Or maybe capacitors aren't the answer?

Using a voltmeter (on amp mode) it looked like the DC motors pulled about 1.5 amps on startup, and then went down to 0.5 amps on steady state.

Whatever the answer, a detailed explanation of wiring would be helpful, as well as what numbers I need to consider when picking out a capacitor or whatever it is I need to buy.

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope to capture any waveforms? Would help. Adding capacitance to the regulator output might help. Putting the arduino on a separate regulator would also help. There is also a possibility that you are not losing voltage, but instead, the turn-on transient is causing a reset pin to be asserted or something like that.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an oscilloscope.  However, if disconnect the motors so the relay still closes but the motors don't actually draw power then the problem disappears.  Sorry, I'm too noobish to understand what you mean by the "turn on transient...reset pin" thing, but does that rule that issue out?

Comment: No, that doesn't rule it out. But just go one step at a time. Start off by putting a lage electrolytic capacitor on the output of the regulator. Like 1000uF or 470uF. Something like that.

Comment: Exactly which Arduino do you have?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I'm actually using a Seeduino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes up ***a lot***.

Yes, it may well be exactly what you say, in which case the answer is another regulator just for the Arduino.    It's funny, I once went in backflips trying to find a way to share the reg, *and then I found out the regulator was a $4 part... forehead slap*

But what also gets people is voltage drop on the wires from the regulator or battery to the motors+Arduino.  Usually it's like this  (and this is about distribution, so 1 line represents 2 wires)

```
                                                             /- Arduino
   Batt -- Reg ---------------------------------------------<
                                                             \- Motor
```

So you see the recipe for disaster. Even if the reg can deliver the current, when the motors are at Locked Rotor Amperage on startup, that's kicking a big voltage drop down whatever piddly 18 AWG wire the hobbyist happened to grab for that long run.

This means, ***don't do this***

```
                                                        /- Reg -- Arduino    NO
   Batt -----------------------------------------------<                     NO
                                                        \- Reg -- Motor      NO
```

Do this

```
          /----------------------------------------------- Reg -- Arduino
   Batt -<
          \----------------------------------------------- Reg -- Motor
```

Comment: Or use a really thick single wire. For the current levels, something like a 12 ga wire will likely do, although the length has not been specified.

Comment: If you only need one regulator, then it doesn't really matter that it is 4 dollars. If you need 10,000, you can get them for less than a dollar, and if you need a million, it will be like 30 cents of parts.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be inclined, given the huge headroom (15 - 9 = 6 volts), to just use a 2nd regulator for the MCU.

Make sure the motor-regulator (dissipating 1.5 amps * 6 = 9  watts) is well heatsinked.
Or use a switching_reg for the motors.

Answer (score 1):

Measure voltages to see if it is the battery or the power regulator that cannot provide the 1.5A of startup current. Then add a huge capacitor parallel with it.The size of the capacitor depends on how long it takes the motor to reach its running speed.

Comment: It's a monstrous 16,000mah 4s LiPo battery with a 10C discharge, so that can't be the issue.  The power regulator is only rated for 2A.